# Escaping a linux command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, quoting

I'm trying to run a command from a script I wrote that basically replaces a string in file

```
vzctl exec VZID sed -i 's/\/>/address="$IP\/255.255.255.0"\/\>/' "file.xml"
```

The problem is the command losses the `'` and `"`

is there a a way to Escaping command so that it preservers the `'` and `"`? or somehow capsulating it?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, that `vzctl exec` works like `eval`. That is, it constructs a *shell* command line from the concatenation of the arguments it receives. So you should pass it a valid shell command line as argument which would mean another level of quoting.

```
vzctl exec VZID '
  sed -i '\''s/\/>/address="$IP\/255.255.255.0"\/\>/'\'' "file.xml"'
```

Note that `$IP` will *not* be expanded. For that, you'd need either:

```
vzctl exec VZID '
  sed -i '\''s/\/>/address="'"$IP"'\/255.255.255.0"\/\>/'\'' "file.xml"'
```

For it to be expanded by the shell that interprets that `vzctl` command or:

```
vzctl exec VZID '
  sed -i '\''s/\/>/address="'\''"$IP"'\''\/255.255.255.0"\/\>/'\'' "file.xml"'
```

For it to be expanded by the shell that `vzctl exec` invokes (assuming that shell has access to such a `$IP` variable).

Note that it may be easier to use a here-document and store that code in a variable for clarity like:

```
code=$(cat <<EOF
sed -i 's|/>|address="$IP/255.255.255.0"/>|' file.xml
EOF
)
```

(that form of here document does expand the variables (here `$ID`)).

And run it as

```
vzctl exec VZID "$code"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap whole command in quotes and espace the internal with backslashes?

I mean:

```
vzctl exec VZID 'sed -i \'s/\/>/address=\"$IP\/255.255.255.0\"\/\>/\' \"file.xml\"'
```

I'd check also double quotes if the single don't work, but I think they should.

Comment: Except with the `fish` shell, you can't escape `'` with `\'` inside `'...'`.